# Map marker with multiple drawables

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a map with some markers, and each of them has icons. My thinking, is it possible to add another icon/drawable to an existing one. For example, a map pin, after a click on it, the icon/drawable is added at the bottom right.[image]

Comment: Maybe you can use combined pictures to generate bitmap put in the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two drawables

1. Without bottom icon
2. With bottom icon

When you click on marker, you can simply replace 1st marker icon with another let me know if you need code to draw custom marker on maps

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. That was my last option, I thought there was a another way, but I think this will have to do the job. Thanks! :)

Comment: Thanks, if it's the solution you can simply mark this as correct answer. Let me know if anything more help required Thanks